# Where to set await in delegate action

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
public enum SyncListsEnum
{
    Country = 1,
    Language = 2
}

public class SyncListsService
{
    private readonly WeCandidateContext _db;
    private readonly IRestClientFactory _factory;
    private readonly IConfigurationService _configService;

    private readonly Dictionary<SyncListsEnum, Action<IList<ExpandoObject>>> _syncLists;

    public SyncListsService(WeCandidateContext db, IRestClientFactory factory, IConfigurationService configService)
    {
        _db = db;
        _factory = factory;
        _configService = configService;

        _syncLists = new Dictionary<SyncListsEnum, Action<IList<ExpandoObject>>>()
        {
            {SyncListsEnum.Country, items =>{ new CountrySync(_db).SyncItems(items); _db.SaveChangesAsync();}},
            {SyncListsEnum.Language, items =>{ new LanguageSync(_db).SyncItems(items); _db.SaveChangesAsync();}}
        };
    }

    public async Task SyncList(string listName)
    {
        SyncListsEnum list;
        if (!Enum.TryParse(listName, true, out list)) return;


        // get list content from Recruiter 
        var items = await GetListFromRecruiter();
        // call a specific routine for each list to handle insert/update/delete 
        if (items != null)
        {
            // Synchronizes the local table with items retrieced from Recruiter.
            this._syncLists[list](items);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code all are correct but i need `await _db.SaveChangesAsync()` instead of `_db.SaveChangesAsync()`. If i put *await* operator in front of *_db.SaveChangesAsync()*, it shows me an error like **await operator can only be used within an async lamda expression**.

Now where should i use *async* keyword to resolved this error.

Comment: I guess it would be better to return the `Task` without adding `await` in the delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `async` in front of your lambda expressions, then you can use `await`. See "[can not await async lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046096/can-not-await-async-lambda)"

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015319/where-do-i-mark-a-lambda-expression-async