# Better way to show error messages in async methods

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, try-catch, modal-dialog, async-await

The fact that we can't use the `await` keyword in `catch` blocks makes it quite awkward to show error messages from async methods in WinRT, since the `MessageDialog` API is asynchronous. Ideally I would like be able to write this:

```
    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Some code that can throw an exception
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong!");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

But instead I have to write it like this:

```
    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        bool error = false;
        try
        {
            // Some code that can throw an exception
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = true;
        }

        if (error)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong!");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

All methods that need to do this have to follow a similar pattern, which I really don't like, because it reduces the code readability.

Is there a better way to handle this?

---

*EDIT:* I came up with this (which is similar to what svick suggested in his comments):

```
static class Async
{
    public static async Task Try(Func<Task> asyncAction)
    {
        await asyncAction();
    }

    public static async Task Catch<TException>(this Task task, Func<TException, Task> handleExceptionAsync, bool rethrow = false)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        TException exception = null;
        try
        {           
            await task;
        }
        catch (TException ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }

        if (exception != null)
        {
            await handleExceptionAsync(exception);
            if (rethrow)
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Async.Try(async () => 
    {
        // Some code that can throw an exception
        ...
    })
    .Catch<Exception>(async ex =>
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong!");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    });
}
```

`.Catch<...>` calls can be chained to mimick multiple `catch` blocks.

But I'm not really happy with this solution; the syntax is even more awkward than before...

Comment: Couldn't you just encapsulate that into a method? Something like `AsyncTryCatch(async () => /* Some code that can throw an exception */, async ex => /* error handling */)`.

Comment: Do you really need to show a message box? Perhaps something like a message panel where you print exceptions would do?

Comment: @svick, yes, I thought of something like that, but it's still not very convenient; for instance, it doesn't support multiple catch clauses, and doesn't tell me whether the operation succeeded.

Comment: @athabaska, no, that's not an option. Anyway, my question isn't limited to showing message boxes, it's more about find a workaround for the "no await in catch" rule.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Normal `try`-`catch` doesn't tell you whether the operation succeeded, but the method could by returning a `bool`. And multiple `catch` clauses could be done something like this: `AsyncTryCatch(async () => /* whatever */, async (SomeException ex) => /* handle SomeException */, async (AnotherException ex) => /* handle AnotherException */)`. Though you would need overloads for each number of `catch` clauses.

Comment: I have used this type of solution before as well and I agree that it is ugly. In this very specific case, where it seems you want to wait for the dialog's result, why not simply invoke it as in: `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong!");
            var result = dialog.ShowAsync().GetResults();
        }`

Comment: @Alex, because it doesn't work: the dialog is shown on the UI thread, which would be blocked on the call to GetResults (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179035/98713))

Comment: Is that still true if you insert an intermediate step, as in: `        public static async Task DontBlockUi(Task asyncUiTask)
        {
            await asyncUiTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }`

Comment: @Alex, interesting idea, but no, it doesn't work (just tried it). It just blocks the UI forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# 6 now supports `await` in `catch` and `finally`, so the code can be written the way I wanted it; a workaround is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

you already have that functionality in TPL

```
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // Some code that can throw an exception
            ...
        }).ContinueWith(async (a) =>
        {
            if (a.IsFaulted)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong!\nError: "
                           + a.Exception.Message);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                var dialog2 = new MessageDialog("Everything is OK: " + a.Result);
                await dialog2.ShowAsync();
            }
        }).Unwrap();
```

In this machine I don't have Windows 8 so I tested in Windows 7 but I think is the same.
*Edit
as stated in the comments its needed .Unwrap(); in the end for the await to work

Comment: It's not really the same, because in this case the continuation is an `async void`, so it's not awaited; if I add some code after the ContinueWith call, it could run before the continuation is complete.

Comment: Also, the syntax is still a mess... but I'm beginning to think there's no way around that.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque after reading your comment I started to try and as i don't have a windows 8 machine can you try an see if  dialog.ShowAsync().Wait(); is valid inside the catch

Comment: Yes, it's valid (in the sense that it will compile), but it won't work, for the reason explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178764/messagedialog-task-not-shown-if-i-use-task-wait-instead-of-await/11179035#11179035)

Comment: This won't work correctly. Your `ContinueWith()` returns a `Task<Task>` and to wait for that properly, you either need `await await`, or you need to use `Unwrap()`.

Comment: @svick just because I didn't put the Unwrap at the end it doesn't make the answer wrong it was just a generic approach to the problem.